# How to test multiple conditions in the 'Then' step of a CucumberBDD test?

Tags: cucumber, assertion, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

We are using CucumberBDD for our tests. For assertions we use JUnit.
Now in our **Given**, **When**, **Then** steps we use multiple **'And'** steps which do variety of activities. Until this point this is fine, we were able to do it. At the last **'Then'** step should be final check whether the Scenario has *PASSED* or *FAILED*, based on the multiple **'And'** steps of **'Then'** branch itself.

One solution is to use ***JUnitSoftAssertions*** from assertJ library to pool multiple checks, if it is a pure JUnit project which our project is NOT.

As per Cucumber documentation, it only supports JUnit Assert class and it's various assertion methods, nothing more. According to that, you can have only one assertion per scenario.

Is there any means you can incorporate multiple checks which may fail or pass individually, after the final **'Then'** step by using keyword **'And'** multiple times?

Comment: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/771#issuecomment-338202125

Answer (score 0):

Give the multiple conditions a name. Write a single step using that name.

Say you have

```
Then foo
And bar 
And baz
```

then you can say qux = foo and bar and baz and just wriete

```
Then qux
```

You can apply this pattern to any number of checks.